# AngularJS - modal insere template com opções de radiobutton

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um botão que abre um modal, onde serão digitadas palavras separadas por vírgulas que se tornarão as opções do radiobutton na pagina principal. Quando salvar o modal deve inserir um template HTML com esses dados incorporados.

Segue
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pNfseJMjIszHIY6U87Pi?p=preview)

Comment: Faltou o import para o angular-ui.bootstrap, não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4OyrkNp3VyzWdzXmrvxg?p=preview) contém as seguintes correções para o funcionamento da sua modal:

Foram importados os arquivos de script do ui.bootstrap;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Adicionada importação da biblioteca para o `module`:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Adicionado `service` para passagem de variáveis:

```
angular
  .module('plunker')
  .factory('serviceModal', serviceModal);

serviceModal.$inject = [];

function serviceModal() {
  var opcoes = "";

  return {
    setOpcoes: setOpcoes,
    getOpcoes: getOpcoes
  }

  function setOpcoes(novasOpcoes) {
    this.opcoes = novasOpcoes;
  }

  function getOpcoes() {
    if (this.opcoes === undefined) {
      this.opcoes = "";
    }

    return this.opcoes;
  }
}
```

Adicionadas injeções de dependência no `controller` principal para `$uibModal`, `$timeout`e `serviceModal`:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $timeout, serviceModal)
```

Utilização do `service` para passagem de variáveis:

```
serviceModal.setOpcoes($scope.data.opcoes);
```

**e**

```
$scope.verificarOpcoes = function() {
  var op = serviceModal.getOpcoes();

  if (op !== undefined && op !== "") {
    return op.split(",");
  }
}
```

Comment: a questão do modal eu ja havia resolvido, o plunker que vc abriu provavelmente não esta atualizado.Ps. no plunker vc deve restaurar a sessão para ver a versao atualizada. O que preciso é inserir o template através do modal.

Comment: Esse plunker que você está enviando não funciona, só mostra um alerta. Você salvou ele?

Comment: Salvei, do lado esquerdo do plunker, você restaura a sessão (restore)

Comment: Vou alterar o meu aqui e mando de novo

Comment: Alterado, verifique por favor se a idéia é essa

Comment: o sistema vai montar formularios, então tenho um menu com varias opções como textbox,dropdowlist,radiobutton. Então ocorrerão diversos blocos com esses campos. O modal é para ja inserir as informações nesses controles, por isso nao posso deixar na index ja o input radio, neste caso terei que usar um arquivo externo como _checkradio.html de onde vem a estrutra de cada elemento.

Comment: Não vai fazer diferença. Você estará usando um service pra passar a informação. Esse exemplo é pra te dar uma idéia de como você passa informação entre controllers. A essência é a mesma, você só vai ter outros controllers usando o mesmo service e fazer basicamente a mesma coisa que está sendo feita na index.html.